# Difference between window.showmodaldialog and window.open

Tags: javascript

Can any one tell me the difference between these functions?

Comment: Isn't this Javascript? Why is this tagged asp.net?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`window.open` opens a new independent window. It works in most browsers in some way (although pop-up blockers often block them or require additional user confirmation). It is possible to access the document that opened the window using the `window.opener` property.

`showModalDialog` opens a dialog that is tied to the current page. It is impossible to do anything on the page until the dialog gets closed. ([MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759(VS.85).aspx))

The most important distinction between the two is that `showModalDialog` halts the execution of the JavaScript until the dialog box is closed, and can return a [return value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534371(VS.85).aspx) (at least in Internet Explorer). In that, it works similar e.g. to the `confirm()` dialog. In contrast, `window.open` opens a window "asynchronously": script execution will continue immediately, even while the new window loads.

It is possible to access the parent document from the dialog with some property whose name I can't remember right now, but it is different from `window.open`.

One more thing to note is that in my experience, modal dialogs are awfully difficult to refresh, as they seem to be subject to different caching rules than normal pages. The F5 key won't work to refresh the page. One workaround is to use a random addition to the loaded URL every time (`pagename.htm?random=1203402920`)

In general, seeing as `showModalDialog` is a proprietary function and its functionality can't be easily ported to other browsers, it's usually best not to use it.

Comment: the property name you were looking for (from the popup) is `window.opener`

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN

> A modal dialog box retains the input
>   focus while open

This means that while it's open the user cannot obtain focus on the Window it was opened from. Window.Open will create a new Window.

Answer (score 1):

Showmodaldialog will do exactly as it says, show a *modal* dialog, ie a window that the user needs to close first before he can get back to the original window, window.open will just open a new window, but the user is free to ignore this and get back to the original window whenever he wants.